# need for japan transit visa

Tags: usa, transit, japan, filipino-citizens, jal

I am a Filipino citizen and is scheduled to go to the US on January 2020 . My brother from Canada booked me a ticket via Japan airlines. However , my itinerary is Manila -Haneda and Narita - US. This means that I need to go out  from Haneda Airport in order to get to Narita Airport . My question is , do i need to have a transit visa from Hanedon to Narita ? My lay over is only 6 hours. Need to be enlighyened on this. Thanks.

Comment: Was there a particular reason for choosing this routing? Normally Filipino citizens can transit without a visa if they stay in the international area of the airport. Timatic indicates you may be eligible for a ‘shore pass’ if there’s no connecting flight on your day of arrival https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true